# SECP256K1 Verify using SawTooth Swift

Tags: swift, cryptography, elliptic-curve, apple-cryptokit

I'm trying to use SawTooth SDK in order to make a sign/verify of a Secp256k1 keys pair. Everyone seems to be great expect the end when I try to verify :

```
let context = Secp256k1Context()

//PrivateKey init
let privateKey = Secp256k1PrivateKey.init(privKey: [0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0xf4,0x27,0x86,0xb5,0xdd,0x7b,0x76,0xba,0xea,0x42,0xa9,0xaa,0x60,0xff,0x4c,0x31,0x23,0xfa,0xf0,0x9b,0x8a])

//PublicKey init
let publicKey = Secp256k1PublicKey.init(pubKey: [0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x..,0x6c,0xd0,0x7b,0xd5,0xa3,0x85,0x6f,0x92,0xe7,0xbc,0x15,0xf3,0x40,0x8a,0xa5,0x4f,0x6c,0x3c,0x11,0x55,0x25,0x37,0x48,0xc9,0x93,0x0d,0x7a,0x18,0x4b,0x29,0x30,0xde,0xcd,0xbf,0xb3,0x94,0x4c,0x7f,0xdf,0xd2,0xda,0x51,0xcd,0x87,0xb5,0x00,0x8a,0x15,0xc5,0x16,0x1c,0x73,0xca])

let message_string = "hello"
let message_bytes: [UInt8] = Array(message_string.utf8)

let signer = Signer(context: context, privateKey: privateKey)

do {
    let signature = try signer.sign(data: message_bytes)
    let verif = try context.verify(signature: signature, data: message_bytes, publicKey: publicKey)
    print(verif)
}
catch {
    print("Verification failed..")
}
```

I always get "Verification failed..." Any idea what I'm making wrong ? Thanks!

Comment: You are explicitly defining the priv/pub keys, are you sure they are correct? with this curve you calculate the public key by scalar multiplication of the private key with the curves generator point.

Comment: Ahh I think you are right. These keys were generated for Secp256r1 not k1. So it's normal that it doesn't work no ?

Comment: added an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer based on our discussion above.

Yes, you're exactly right.

`secp256r1` is a curve defined as:

`y^2 = x^3-3x+41058363725152142129326129780047268409114441015993725554835256314039467401291`

These constants, come from our friends at the NSA.

`secp256k1` on the other hand is a curve defined by the equation:

`y^2 = x^3+0x+7`

There may be some cross over with regard to `x`,`y` co-ordindates that satisfy both of the curve equations, however, with regard to signature processes above, the public keys are not interchangeable with regard to the signing context.

Remember that private keys in ECC are simply `256-bit` numbers, however each curve has it's own defined generator point `G`, which must be scalar multiplied by the private key to obtain the public key (which is simply a point on the curve itself).

So, you just need to define the private key as a `256-bit` number, and multiply this by the `y^2 = x^3+0x+7` curves generator point, `02 79BE667E F9DCBBAC 55A06295 CE870B07 029BFCDB 2DCE28D9 59F2815B 16F81798`.

By the way, the above is the raw math required to find the public key, in your `sawtooth SDK`, you can just use [this](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/sdk-java/nightly/master/java_docs/signing/sawtooth/sdk/signing/Secp256k1Context.html#getPublicKey(sawtooth.sdk.signing.PrivateKey)) method to derive the public key from the private key.